# Existe alguma função javascript que marque um texto aleatório selecionado com o mouse?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olá, vocês sabem se é possível criar um marcador de texto, parecido com os utilizados em pdf, porém em um html? Não necessariamente ele precisaria salvar as marcações, porém se salvasse seria melhor.

Valeu!

Comment: seria [isso](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_lists4)?

Comment: Como assim marcar o texto? Seria algo mais ou menos como isso: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_formatting_mark ?

Comment: Olá! Desta forma também consigo. É que achei que daria muito trabalho se tivesse que marcar todas as palavras com tags e depois fazer uma função javascript para que as marque conforme selecionadas. Então estava pensando se era possível selecionar um trecho de uma tag "p", por exemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, encontrei esta biblioteca JavaScript pesquisando na web. Agora irei pesquisar uma forma de salvar as marcações.
[TextHighlighter](http://mir3z.github.io/texthighlighter/demos/simple.html)

Answer (score 3):

Pelo que compreendi, seria algo relacionado a isso?

```js
var textMark = null;
var textStart = 0;
var textStop = 0;

function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    var select = null;
    if (window.getSelection){
        select = window.getSelection();
        text = select.toString();
        textMark = select.anchorNode.textContent;
        textStart = select.anchorOffset;
        textStop = select.focusOffset;
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}

function mark(elements){
    var textSelected = getSelectionText();
    if(textSelected.length > 0){
        for(var i in elements){
            var element     = elements[i];
            var html        = element.innerHTML;
            var htmlParts   = html.split(/(?=(?:<\/?mark>))/);
            var htmlPartsClear  = [];
            var divClear = document.createElement('div');
            for(var i in htmlParts){
                divClear.innerHTML = htmlParts[i];
                htmlPartsClear.push(divClear.textContent);
            }
            var index       = htmlPartsClear.indexOf(textMark);
            var change      = htmlParts[index];
            if(change.length >= textStop){

                var lenMarks = 0;
                var matchs = change.match(/<\/?mark>/g);
                for (var i in matchs){
                    lenMarks += matchs[i].length;
                }

                var r = new RegExp('(.{'+(textStart+lenMarks)+'})(.{'+(textStop-textStart)+'})(.*)');
                change = change.replace(r, '$1<mark>$2</mark>$3');

                htmlParts[index] = change;
            }
            element.innerHTML = htmlParts.join('');
        }
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    var elementsCheck = [];

    var allowMark = 0;
    var timerToMark = 0.5;
    var timer = null;

    $('p').on('mouseover', function(){
        allowMark = 1;
        elementsCheck.push(this);
    });
    $('p').on('mouseout', function(){
        allowMark = 0;
        var i = elementsCheck.indexOf(this);
        if (i > -1) {
            elementsCheck.splice(i, 1);
        }
    });

    $(document).on('mousemove', function(){
        if(allowMark){
            clearInterval(timer);
            var current = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < elementsCheck.length; i++){
                current.push(elementsCheck[i]);
            }
            timer = setTimeout(function(){
                mark(current);
            }, timerToMark*1000);
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Selecionar parte do texto (abaixo) e aguardar 500ms</h3>
<p>Lorem Ipsum é simplesmente uma simulação de texto da indústria tipográfica e de impressos, e vem sendo utilizado desde o século XVI, quando um impressor desconhecido pegou uma bandeja de tipos e os embaralhou para fazer um livro de modelos de tipos. Lorem Ipsum sobreviveu não só a cinco séculos, como também ao salto para a editoração eletrônica, permanecendo essencialmente inalterado. Se popularizou na década de 60, quando a Letraset lançou decalques contendo passagens de Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente quando passou a ser integrado a softwares de editoração eletrônica como Aldus PageMaker.</p>
```

#### Nota

- Isso é a introdução, tem muita coisa que da fazer ainda.
- Não testei em todos navegadores, apenas no FF 50.

Comment: testado no Chrome e está Ok! +1

Comment: Muito maneiro isso. Existira alguma forma de apagar seleções?

Comment: Reparei apenas que ele buga dependendo da marcação. Parece que ele vai sempre marcar a primeira ocorrência da letra ou sequência de letras marcadas e pode interferir até no `<mark>`. `Exemplo`: Se você marcar apenas um `m` no meio do parágrafo e depois um `a` no meio do parágrafo, você vai ver que ele vai marcar o `a` do `<mark>` e bugar.

Comment: @LeonFreire estou vendo isso ja edito

Comment: Cara, perfeito. Estou desenvolvendo alguns livros interativos para a rede pública de educação. Estava quebrando a cabeça com isto. Valeu mesmo.

Comment: @LeonFreire Agora sim, esta ok :D

Comment: @MarcioDosSantos, de nada, faça bom uso :D. Recomendo ver a atualização.

Answer (score 0):

> By Imran Bughio [Selecting text with mouse and highlighting the same text with multiple occurences in that div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23881509/selecting-text-with-mouse-and-highlighting-the-same-text-with-multiple-occurence/23881845#23881845)

```js
//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){


thisRespondHightlightText(".select--highlight--active");


function thisRespondHightlightText(thisDiv){
    $(thisDiv).on("mouseup", function () {
        var selectedText = getSelectionText();
        var selectedTextRegExp = new RegExp(selectedText,"g");
        var text = $(this).text().replace(selectedTextRegExp, "<span class='red'>" + selectedText + "</span>");
        $(this).html(text);
    });
}

function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return text;
}
});//]]>
```

```css
    .red {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

    
  <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    
    
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  
    <div class="select--highlight--active">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
```

Comment: Interessante e rápido. Porém, parece que ele marca todas as ocorrências do texto selecionado.

Comment: Foi o que pensei que ele queria mas acho que não.

Comment: Entendi. Mesmo assim é uma informação muito interessante e vale guardar. ;)